Tikz: Custom Style for Complex Nodes
Tikz (Beamer)
I need to create the following figure as efficiently as possible (minimal code) in tikz:

Right now I can define nodes with styles manually, then draw lines and arrows etc. But this is a lot of work. Any way to define a custom style for a complex node and reuse it ?
I also want it to "animate" or overlay. i.e revealing children nodes one by one. Wrapping nodes inside \only< > seems to be a lot of repetitive work. I have to first draw a node without outline, then hide it and redraw it with outline and formatting in the next slide etc.
Any way to achieve this too with minimal reusable code ?

On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a minimal working example (MWE): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Of course you can define custom styles, you can set up styles for every node for example, but you can also create you own styles. Check the TikZ manual for how to do this: https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-styleoptions#sec-4.18.1

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\tikzset{
complexnode/.style={
draw=blue, thick,
inner sep=8pt,
rounded corners=6pt,
label={[draw=blue, thick, fill=white, anchor=south, yshift=-4pt, inner xsep=10pt]north:#1},
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[complexnode=24] {$\operatorname{mul}(4,\,6)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Nice idea, +1 //   : )

24 is a label feature of the current node. Is it possible to add multiple nodes within a style to create complex styles? Like "complexnode" style made up of three nodes: mul, 24, and the big bold line underneath.

A label is a node (an extra node). You can add any number of labels. Please ask a new question if you need help. Include compilable code of what you have tried and a link to this question for context.
